# $\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)=z+1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ where $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, exponential-function

I want to proof that

$\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)=z+1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ where $|z|<1$

As a hint it is given to observe $\frac{d}{dz} \frac{f(z)}{z+1}$.

So I tried to calculate

$\frac{d}{dz}\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)}{z+1}$

$=\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}z^{n-1}\right)(z+1)-\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)}{(z+1)^2}$

$=\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{n}}{n}\right)\left(\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}z^{n+1}\right)(z+1)-1\right)}{(z+1)^2}$

$=\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{n}}{n}\right)\left(\left(\frac{\color{red}{-z}}{z+1}\right)(z+1)-1\right)}{(z+1)^2}$

$=-\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)}{z+1}$

I do not see my mistake, in this calculation.

I would suspect to receive $0$, implying that the original function is constant, hence

$\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)=c(z+1)$

Then plugging in $z=0$ this leads to $c=1$, and I would be done.

Instead, I derive that the derivative of $\frac{f(z)}{z+1}$ is $-\frac{f(z)}{z+1}$, which can not be correct, as I know that this should be $0$.

This factor $\color{red}{-z}$ breaks the calculation. Without that I just would get a $0$, but I do not see why this should be wrong, as

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}z^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}z^{n+1}=-z\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-z)^n=-z\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-z)}=\frac{-z}{1+z}$.

I can not see any other mistake.

Can you tell me what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have $$\frac{d}{dz}\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)}{z+1}$$

$$=\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{\color{red}{n=1}}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}z^{n-1}\right)(z+1)-\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)}{(z+1)^2}$$

$$=\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{n}}{n}\right)\left(\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}z^{n}\right)(z+1)-1\right)}{(z+1)^2}$$
$$=\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{n}}{n}\right)\left(\left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)(z+1)-1\right)}{(z+1)^2}=0.$$

Comment: Why do I not have to shift the index? I used this theorem for derivative of convergent series, that the derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot a_nz^{n-1}$. So I changed $n=1$ to $n=2$.

Comment: (+1) All too easy

Comment: Ah, I see, if I shift from n=1 to n=0 before I take the derivative, I get to the correct solution. Odd that this makes a difference. So the theorem can only be applied if the series starts with $n=0$ in general? I thought it does not matter. Lesson learned, I guess.

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}z^{n-1}=-z+z^2-...$, but what about the first term? Differentiating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}=z-\frac{z^2}{2}+..$ we find that the first term is $1$. The shift of index only works when the derivative of the first term is zero!

Comment: You are absolutly right. Thanks. This tricked me...